# Mess with content height

Tags: html, css

I want to add two div one after another. Though position relative works fine. But why this happen without position. Is it possible do that without position.

Here is html part:

```
<div class="content1">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text
<div>
<div class="content2">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text
<div>
```

And CSS Part:

```
.content1{
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.content2{
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```css
.content1{
 width: 100%;
 height: 400px;
 border: 1px solid black;
}
.content2{
 width: 100%;
 height: 300px;
 border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="content1">
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text
 <div>
<div class="content2">
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text
<div>
```

Comment: just close the div tag..remaining every thing is okay ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not closing your `<div>`s correctly.

To close a `<div>` block, use `</div>`. Like this:

```
<div class="content1">
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text
</div> <!-- Changed -->
<div class="content2">
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text
</div> <!-- Changed -->
```

Comment: Thanks. Missed that on pressure.

Answer (score 2):

Simply close your `<div>` tags

```css
.content1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  
}
.content2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="content1">
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text
</div>
<div class="content2">
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Close your `div` tags

```
<div class="content1">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</div>
<div class="content2">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</div>
```